# Transparent child inside of Non-transparent parent

Tags: jquery, html, css, transparency

Another way to ask this (if you know illustrator/photoshop) is can you subtract a child from the parent?

Is there a way using jQuery or some other tool (because I doubt CSS is powerful enough) to do this?

[image]

My goal with this is to use it as an "active page" indicator. So when about is the active page (page that's being viewed) there is a small triangle indicator that is transparent through the parent so you see the background of the body.

Comment: CSS can be powerful --> check clip-path

Answer (score 4):

You can't get transparent background from the child element, but you can design a specific shape with css. In that way you can show the background where you want. Try this example:

```css
#myParentDiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

#myDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 60%, 53% 60%, 53% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 60%, 53% 60%, 53% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="myParentDiv">
  <div id="myDiv">
    My div
  </div>
</div>
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/alexdant91/s4zxLqhr/3/

To design a new shape you can use a super easy and powerfull tool here:

http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

I hope that will help you.

Comment: Thanks! That pointed me in the right direction! I ended up doing..
.activeNav-triangle{
                            width: 0; 
                            height: 0; 
                            border-top: 10px solid transparent;
                            border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
                            border-right:10px solid #333; 
                            position: absolute;
                            right: 0;
                            top: 17px;
                        }